# join tag not allowed in hibernate mapping file `class` tag

Tags: hibernate

Xml referenced some where, my error is `The content of class tag must match ....` thus I cannot use join inside `class` tag.

```
<hibernate-mapping package="beans">
<class name="TABLE1Class" table="TABLE1">
<composite-id name="table1PK" class="TABLE1PKClass">
    <key-many-to-one name="id1" class="ID1Class" column="id1"/>
    <key-many-to-one name="id2" class="ID2Class" column="id2"/>
    <key-many-to-one name="id3" class="ID3Class" column="id3"/>
</composite-id>
<property name="someProperty" type="integer" not-null="true" column="x"/>
<join table="TABLE2">
    <key column="id1" />
        <property name="propertyFromTable2" type="float" not-null="true"/>
</join>

<joined-subclass>
    some joined subclass
</joind-subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

code is referenced somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),

meaning: join/joined-subclass/union-subclass can not be mixed together for usage.